# is there any bug with math.sum(series, period)?

Tags: debugging, pine-script

when I use the math.sum() to sum the last several values, it gives me the wrong answer.only the period is 1, it will be ok.

for example:

```
// MACD hist
hist = [series]
math.sum(hist, 7)
```

does anyone also get the problem?

Comment: We need more information here. What do you think is the wrong answer? What do you expect and what do you get? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is a great chance that you are doing or expecting something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

now I use this way to replace:

```
sumup := 0.0
for i = 1 to 7
    sumup := sumup + hist[i]
```